# How to create search queries in SQL with optional search parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a general pattern for creating search queries with optional parameters? I am thinking that we should be able to build a multi-part `where` clause, but nullify the parts that have not been specified. Also some query parameters may require joins and I would like to nullify them if the associated query parameters are not specified.

**Example** (see full code [here](https://github.com/sapientglobalmarkets/staffer/tree/master/staffer-sql))

Think of a staffing domain. It consists of Projects, Needs, People and Skills. We would like to search for needs based on the following criteria:

```
1. min_start_date
2. max_start_date
3. project_id
4. project_location
5. skill_id
```

Here are the relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(64),
  location VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE needs (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  start_date TIMESTAMPTZ,
  end_date TIMESTAMPTZ,
  project_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  skill_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE skills (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
```

Here's the query for the search:

```
\set min_start_date '2016-08-01T00:00:00-04'
\set max_start_date '2016-08-31T00:00:00-04'
\set project_id 71
\set project_location 'DEN'
\set skill_id 4

SELECT n.id, n.start_date, n.end_date
FROM   needs n
       LEFT OUTER JOIN projects p
                    ON n.project_id = p.id
WHERE  n.start_date >= :'min_start_date'
  AND  n.start_date <  :'max_start_date'
  AND  p.id = :'project_id'
  AND  p.location = :'project_location'
  AND  s.id = :'skill_id'
ORDER  BY n.start_date, p.id, s.id;
```

What I want is the ability nullify parts of the where clause depending on which query parameters are specified. Also there should be no need to perform the join if the search parameter `project_location` is not specified.

**Edit**

Based on Neil McGuigan's comment, I tried this:

```
\set min_start_date 2016-08-01T00:00:00-04

SELECT *
FROM   needs n
WHERE  (:'min_start_date' IS NULL OR n.start_date >= :'min_start_date');
```

This works correctly and produces the desired result, however when I change the value of `min_start_date` to NULL:

```
\set min_start_date NULL
```

I get the following error from PostgreSQL:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "NULL"
LINE 8: WHERE  ('NULL' IS NULL OR n.start_date >= 'NULL')
                                                  ^
```

Basically I am not able to provide correct types for both sides of the OR. Not sure how to specify NULL parameter values and may the SQL statement work.

Comment: It sure is possible if you supply NULL values for the unneeded params but you should generate the query dynamically and just don't include those parts.

Comment: When you say *generate the query dynamically* do you mean string concatenation to produce a custom query every time? That would mean no prepared statements at all, correct? I was hoping that there would be a better way.

Comment: You appear to be quoting your bind variables - there's no need - you're checking to see whether the string `'NULL'` is NULL, or whether a date is greater than or equal to a string.

Comment: Well I am stuck both ways, if I quote them then I am comparing `'NULL'` with `NULL`, if I don't quote them then I get a syntax error in the WHERE clause: syntax error at or near "T00": WHERE  (2016-08-01T00:00:00-04...

Comment: The code is checked in here, if you want to try it: https://github.com/sapientglobalmarkets/staffer/blob/master/staffer-sql/search-needs.sql

Comment: That's because you're not defining your timestamp as a timestamp, from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) (for example `TIMESTAMP '2004-10-19 10:23:54'`)

Comment: @Naresh Who said no prepared statement? You generate the query string and a table of params in whatever language you prefer and run it as a prepared statement.

Comment: @Ben, it boils down to how to set timestamp variables in psql. I tried `\set min_start_date TIMESTAMP '2016-08-01 00:00:00-04'` as well as `\set min_start_date '2016-08-01 00:00:00-04'` - both don't work. (I am able to make the query work for the integers though - so that's good).

Comment: @JakubKania, thanks for the clarification. I can see that working now. Any thoughts on pros/cons of this approach (dynamic query generation) vs. checking for null parameters as suggested by Neil McGuigan?

Comment: @Naresh Well, it will certainly be faster since the query is less complicated. I can't see any cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes:

```
where
   (column1Value is null OR column1 = column1Value)
   and (column2Value is null OR column2 = column2Value)
   ...
```

And a join condition is any old predicate, so you can make it as complex as you like

Comment: Thank Neil. This is great. I can almost see it working. However, when I tried it, PostgreSQL was putting quotes around NULL and was interpreting it as a string. Please see my edit above along with the error message.

Comment: It appears that psql variables are just string substitutions (like macros). They are not first class variables with types. I think I can make your basic concept work when I am doing this in a programming language. Marking your answer as correct.